# jquery fade popupwindow

Tags: jquery, popupwindow

I am using the popupwindow plugin for jquery to show a form in a popupwindow.
How can I close this window after submitting?
[This](http://rip747.github.com/popupwindow/) is the link I am talking about. 
I can open a link in a pupup window. But after submitting I want it to open in its parent window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can attach the behavior to your link, in the popup-ed page:

```
<a href="javascript: self.opener.location = 'http://somewhere.ltd/path/to/dir'; self.close();">
     Let's go Somewhere
</a>
```

Additionally, I recommend you to use [Javascript in an unobtrusive way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) instead of using the simple line above.

About that "Fade" operation; You can't do such a thing to the OS window using Javascript (no matter what).

**Update:** Assuming the form with id property `theChildForm` and using jQuery:

```
$("#theChildForm").submit(function() {
     // TODO: Some data keeping jobs to be done
     // Pass the url if needed
     self.opener.location = 'http://somewhere.ltd/path/to/dir';
     self.close();
     // ...
    });
```

Comment: How would i do this if i use a submit input type in a form?

Comment: use the code as the form's submit handler (onsubmit). feel free to tell, if you need an updated answer. http://is.gd/qPg5

Comment: but that's no jquery, is there a way to do it in jquery?

Comment: Sure there is & that's why I told you to use unobtrusive javascript. I'll update the answer.

Comment: so how would my submit button and the jquery code look like in unubstructive js?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Ibox](http://www.ibegin.com/labs/ibox/) or [DHTML Window](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex8/dhtmlwindow.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use this property:

```
window.opener
```

The opener property corresponds to the window that opens the window. When accessed by a child window, it returns the parent window.